# How to access nested elements in an if statement XSLT

Tags: xml, if-statement, dom, xslt

So I need to access a nested element in an if statement.

Below you can see an example of the XML I am using:

```
<Publication>
   <PubName>Avoid the Consumer Apps - How to Collaborate Securely and Productively in the Finance Sector</PubName>
   <Attributes>
    <Attribute>
     <AttributeName>Type</AttributeName>
     <Value>Webinar</Value>
     <ValueText>Webinar</ValueText>
    </Attribute>
   </Attributes>
  </Publication>
```

And here is the XSLT code I am using to try and get to the `Webinar` value:

```
<xsl:for-each select="TradePub.com/PublicationTable/Publication">
<xsl:if test="Attributes/Attribute/Value='Webinar'">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="PubName"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="PubCode"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But this returns nothings, so I am wondering how I can access the `Value` element?

Comment: Since the content of `Value` equals "Webinar", the if-expression evaluates to false and no output is produced. What did you expect?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. The problem cannot be reproduced using your (edited) code: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxDjimz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a predicate on the `Value` element like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="TradePub.com/PublicationTable/Publication">
    <xsl:if test="Attributes/Attribute[Value!='Webinar']">
        <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="PubName"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="PubCode"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Another problem why you don't get any output is that the IF-clause is FALSE in your sample. To get the desired output with the given sample, use

```
<xsl:if test="Attributes/Attribute[Value='Webinar']">
```

instead. Then, the output would be

```
<tr>
  <td>Avoid the Consumer Apps - How to Collaborate Securely and Productively in the Finance Sector</td>
  <td/>    <!-- No 'PubCode' element present -->
</tr>
```